# Installing more then one iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

I was wondering how I would go about keeping Apple's SDK 3.2.1 installed, while also installing the new beta. I am sure this is simple, but wanted to ask before creating a potential problem. Also SKD 2.0 is it possible to get back, like from the Apple site or not?

I am wondering what most programmers are doing to test multiple versions of devices because I hear the iPod crowd is still mostly running 2.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty standard (and recommended even) to install the entire Xcode tool set with the new SDK in a different root directory.  I use `/Developer_SDK3.2` for example.

Comment: yea but you waste a lot of space, especially if you're lame like me and only have a 60 GB drive (intel core solo mac mini :( )

Comment: I completely agree, but this is the only way I've heard it recommended.